# Switch inside a Switch [C# / Unity] not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement

I would like spawn something base on a list.

For example, I would like to spawn a shopping mall of 17 / 21 or 25 unit width.

Then i will spawn 3 store each within the shopping mall.

I expect a method (GStoreDis) will return a list of 3 respective number, when i call the method with either 25 /21/17.

Mall with 17 unit width

1. Layout 1 (10,5,2)
2. Layout 2 (7,5,5)

Mall with 21 unit width

1. Layout 1 (10,6,5)
2. Layout 2 (7,7,7)

Mall with 25 unit width

1. Layout 1 (10,10,5)
2. Layout 2 (9,8,8)

```
    private List<int> GStoreDis(int StoreBlockLength)
    {
        switch (StoreBlockLength)
        {
            case 25:

                switch (Random.Range(1,3 )) //Roll out 1 or 2 
                {

                    case 1:
                        var List2501 = new List<int>()
                    {
                        10,10,5
                    };
                        return List2501;

                    case 2:
                        var List2502 = new List<int>()
                        {
                           9,8,8
                        };
                        return List2502;
                }

             default:

                 Debug.Log("Input must be 17 / 21 / 25");
                break;
        }
    }
```

I only cover the layout of 25 unit width shopping mall for now. Yet unity console keep on saying "not all code paths return a value". It is quite confusing to me, any help will be much apperciated. THanks!

Any Suggestion will do fine

Comment: Something should be returned in default. You are just doing `Debug.Log()` there. Try returning the null value

Answer (score 2):

A `case` in a `switch` in C# must return something or at least break.

Let me reduce your switches to see where the problem lies:

```
switch {
  case:
    switch {
      case: return;
      case: return;
    }
  default:
    break;
}
```

The first case in your outer switch does not return anything if none of the other cases are met. Since C# does [not allow "fall through" when you have code between the cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1283-the-switch-statement), you have to add either a return or a break at the end.

In this case, you could probably just add a simple `break;` after your inner switch and be done with it:

```
switch (StoreBlockLength)
{
    case 25:
        switch (Random.Range(1,3 )) //Roll out 1 or 2 
        {
            // Stuff happens here
        }
        break;

    default:
        Debug.Log("Input must be 17 / 21 / 25");
        break;
}
```

Also, just using break at the end, leaves the method with nothing to return. [As Obscure021 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75775153/switch-inside-a-switch-c-unity-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value/75775280#comment133669253_75775153), you have to add a simple return at the end of the method, like `return null;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, these code giving me headache

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know that `Random.Range(1,3)` will return only 1 or 2, so it is concerned what would happen when any other value is returned. Then the `case 25:` will fall through to the next case, and that is forbidden.

When you change `case 2:` into `default:`, then the compiler knows that every value is handled and that the 'case 25' never falls through to the next case.

And in the final `default`, return *something* (like `null`): the method expects a return value, so every possible code path (even paths that *you* know will never heppen) *must* return a value (or throw an exception).